# ¿Se puede comparar variables con distintos valores? dev-c++

Tags: c++, lua

estoy queriendo comparar varios valores en c++, tipo así:

```
if(valor == 1 or 2 or 3){
}
```

Esto es posible en Lua, con table.find

```
if table.find({1, 2, 3}, valor) then
end
```

y si se cumple uno de los tres valores, funciona correctamente y es mejor que hacerlo así:

```
if(valor == 1 or valor == 2 or valor == 3){}
```

sin embargo, no sé si es posible esto en c++

Answer (score 3):

en C++ quedaría así:

```
if (valor == 1 || valor == 2 || valor == 3)
```

Ahora bien, usando características adicionales de C++ también podríamos conseguir el mismo efecto de una forma, quizás un poco más limpia

Primero necesitamos crear una función que nos permita comparar el valor dado con una serie de valores determinada en tiempo de compilación. Esta función se basa en el uso de plantillas variádicas:

```
template<auto... ts, class T>
constexpr bool
is_any(const T& t) noexcept(noexcept(((t == ts) || ...))) {
    return ((t == ts) || ...);
}
```

Y ahora ya solo nos queda hacer la comparación:

```
if (is_any<1, 2, 3>(valor))
```

Ahora bien, si los valores 1, 2, 3 no son valores fijos sino que pueden variar en tiempo de ejecución, lo mejor es agrupar estos valores en una lista y comprobar entonces si el valor dado se encuentra o no en la lista:

```
std::set<int> valores {1, 2, 3};
if (valores.count(valor) != 0)
```